# Problems implementing the move constructor of unique_resource from p0052r2

Tags: c++, exception, move-semantics, move-constructor

I try to implementet unique_resource from the p0052r2 Proposal.

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0052r2.pdf

The declaration of the constructor from the proposal is:

```
unique_resource(unique_resource&& rhs) 
    noexcept(is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<R> && 
             is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<D>);
```

where R is the resource and D is the deleter.

The behaviour is described as follows:

> If is_nothrow_move_constructible_v is true,  initialize resource
>   from forward(rhs.resource), otherwise initialize resource from
>   rhs.resource.[Note: If construction  of resource throws an
>   exceptionrhs is left owning the resource and will free it in due
>   time.— end  note] Then if is_nothrow_move_constructible_v is true
>   initialize deleter from forward(rhs.deleter), otherwise initialize
>   deleter from rhs.deleter. If construction of deleter throws an
>   exception: if !is_nothrow_move_constructible_v, then
>   rhs.deleter(resource).

I have two questions about this.

1. Why should I initialize using forward(rhs.resource) or rhs.resource instead of std::move(rhs.resource). Same for D.
2. How can I implement the exception handling properly?

Only if the constructor of the deleter throws, I should release the resource.

I currently have:

```
CUniqueResource(CUniqueResource&& rhs) try
    : executeOnDestruction(rhs.executeOnDestruction)
    , resource(std::move(rhs.resource))
    , deleter(std::move(rhs.deleter))
{
    rhs.release();
}
catch (...)
{
    if constexpr(!std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<R>)
    {
        rhs.deleter(resource);
    }

    throw;
}
```

The problem is that the function try block encloses the construction of resource, too. What can I do to catch only exceptions for deleter without introducing a call to the default constructor of deleter.

**Edit:**

I think I found an answer to the second question based on based on eerorika's comment. A member function is used instead of a subobject.

The code looks like this:

```
CUniqueResource(CUniqueResource&& rhs)
    : executeOnDestruction(rhs.executeOnDestruction)
    , resource(std::move(rhs.resource))
    , deleter(acquireDeleter(rhs))
{
    rhs.release();
}

D acquireDeleter(CUniqueResource&& rhs)
{
    try
    {
        return D(std::move(rhs.deleter));
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        if constexpr(!std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<R>)
        {
            rhs.deleter(this->resource);
        }

        throw;
    }
}
```

I think this should work, because C++ guarantees copy ellision for the return value.

Comment: You could separate the deleter into a subobject, and use the function try block in constructor of that object. It's a bit fiddly though.

Comment: This sounds like a possible solution. The Problem with this solution is, that the deleter object has no access to the resource member. I would need to pass it to the subobject as a reference. While this is possible, it isn't nice. Maybe a member function instead? But without introducing addition constructor calls.

Comment: The wrapper subobject should just capture and store the exception if any. The super object could then check the result in body of constructor, and destroy + rethrow.

Comment: Another approach might be to have a raw char storage for the destructor member, so that you can wait until body to initialize it. It's a bit hacky though.

Comment: Is it possible that the `forward<R>` has to do with the fact that `R` is allowed to be an l-value reference?

Comment: Why are you working from something [seven revisions behind](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0052r9.pdf)?